# writing more variables (intern signals of circuit)from Verilog modules (fwrite)

Tags: verilog, simulation

I need to write more variables (intern signals of the circuit)from Verilog modules one by one in a file.

can I automate the scripting without having to specify the name of each signal?

f = $fopen("output.txt", "w");

$fwrite(f, "pc = %d\n", namesignal);

Answer (score -1):

If you wanted to write *all* signals to an output file, you might as well use `$dumpvars` to write to a VCD file. But as soon as you need only a specific set of signals, you need to *specify* the ones you want.

Comment: i don't know if I can write just the output of flip flop  (intern flip flop )from Verilog modules one by one in a file.

can I automate the scripting?

Comment: In order to automate anything, you need to provide an algorithm that identifies which signals you want to write, and when you want to write them. How do you identify an internal flip-fops? If this is RTL, that will be difficult before synthesis.